# Is there a basic implementation of bellman ford's algorithm in julia?

Tags: julia, project, bellman-ford

I'm a first year student who's learning Julia as a first programming language. I have a project about bellman ford's algorithm but it seems every code is a bit more advanced than I can currently understand. Is there a basic code like Dfs or Bfs for this that a starter could understand, if u have, do share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implemented in `LightGraphs`

```
using LightGraphs
g  = erdos_renyi(20, 100, seed=1)
bf_state = bellman_ford_shortest_paths(g, 1)
```

And now we can display all paths found in the graph:

```
julia> enumerate_paths(bf_state)
20-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 []
 [1, 4, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [1, 4]
 [1, 5]
 [1, 11, 6]
 [1, 7]
 [1, 3, 8]
 [1, 3, 9]
 [1, 7, 10]
 [1, 11]
 [1, 12]
 [1, 3, 13]
 [1, 3, 14]
 [1, 15]
 [1, 4, 16]
 [1, 17]
 [1, 3, 18]
 [1, 19]
 [1, 5, 20]
```